# Tab is shifting when widget is not visible

Tags: flutter, widget, show-hide, shift

I am new in Flutter so maybe my question will be basic for someone.

The problem is that in my app I want to hide TextField when CheckBox is unchecked. Next to a TextField is a button which should be static. My issue is that when I want to hide this TextField, button is shifting to the left side. I think that the best option is to show it to you

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

This is the code I am using:

```
bool secondLayer = false;

void _secondLayer(bool value) => setState(() => secondLayer = value);
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      /*appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Name Here'),
      ),*/
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: new Container(
            padding: new EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
            child: new Center(
              child: new Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    child: new Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              new TextField(
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  labelText: 'First Hidden Layer',
                                  hintText: '25',
                                ),
                                autocorrect: true,
                                autofocus: true,
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              new SizedBox(
                                  width: 100,
                                  child: new RaisedButton(onPressed: null, child: new Text('ADD DATA'),)
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: new CheckboxListTile(
                        value: secondLayer,
                        onChanged: _secondLayer,

                        title: new Text(
                            'Use Second Hidden Layer',
                            style: new TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 12
                            ),
                        ),
                        controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                    ),

                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: new Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Visibility(
                          visible: secondLayer,
                          child: new Expanded(
                            child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                new TextField(
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    labelText: 'Second Hidden Layer',
                                    hintText: '25',
                                  ),
                                  autocorrect: true,
                                  autofocus: true,
                                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              new SizedBox(
                                width: 100,
                                child: new RaisedButton(onPressed: null, child: new Text('OPTIONS'),)
                              )

                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: new TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Epochs',
                        hintText: '5000',
                      ),
                      autocorrect: true,
                      autofocus: true,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: new TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Learning Rate',
                        hintText: '0.00333',
                      ),
                      autocorrect: true,
                      autofocus: true,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                    child: new Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/3,
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border.all(color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 100)),
                          ),
                          child: new Text('data')
                        ),
                        Container(
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/3,
                            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              border: Border.all(color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 100)),
                            ),
                            child: new Text('data')
                        )
                      ],
                    )
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )
          )
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you didn't add any `replacement` property to your `Visibility` Widget.

```dart
Visibility(
   visible: secondLayer,
   child: Expanded(
      child: Column(
         children: <Widget>[
            // your text field here
         ]
      ),
   ),
   replacement: Expanded(child: Container()), // the widget which will fill the space when hiddden
)
```

Something like this should work as you replace your `TextField` with an empty `Container` inside an `Expanded` to fill your empty space.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `maintainSize` property of the `Visibility` widget to `true`, it is used to decide "whether to maintain space for where the widget would have been." [Source](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Visibility/maintainSize.html)

You also need to set `maintainAnimation` and `maintainState` to `true` for `maintainSize` to work. [Source](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Visibility/Visibility.html)

So your code will go from:

```
Visibility(
     visible: secondLayer,
     child: yourChildWidget
),
```

to:

```
Visibility(
   visible: secondLayer,
   maintainSize: true,
   maintainAnimation: true,
   maintainState: true,
   child: yourChildWidget
),
```